# Json Error on characters

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a json like the one below :

```
{"total":null,"data":null}{"total":3,"data":[{"id":"12552116",
"advertiser":"Do Planet Elektronik Ticaret ve Biliim Hizmetleri 
    A..","advertiser_id":"1990","offer_id":"1290","goal_id":"1368","goal_name":"n11.CPR",
    "advertiser_info":"1921504","datetime":"2014-02-02 11:27:05","t_datetime":"2014-02-02 11:15:47","comission":"0.000000","amount":"0.000000","source":"1","status":"approved"},{"id":"12552536","advertiser":"Do Planet Elektronik Ticaret ve Biliim Hizmetleri 
    A..","advertiser_id":"1990","offer_id":"1290","goal_id":"1348","goal_name":"n11.CPS","advertiser_info":"202681752960_KK","datetime":"2014-02-02 12:12:29","t_datetime":"2014-02-02 
    12:10:52","comission":"6.500000","amount":"305.000000","source":"1624","status":"approved"},{"id":"12558426","advertiser":"Do Planet Elektronik Ticaret ve Biliim Hizmetleri 
    A..","advertiser_id":"1990","offer_id":"1290","goal_id":"1348","goal_name":"n11.CPS","advertiser_info":"203982552963_KK","datetime":"2014-02-02 22:28:01","t_datetime":"2014-02-02 22:20:53","comission":"6.500000","amount":"144.900000","source":"4256","status":"approved"}]}
```

when i want to  do that command:

`decoded = json.loads(self.contents)`

I back an error: "ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 26 - line 1 column 1089 (char 26 - 1089)
"

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: This is an invalid JSON.

Comment: Yeah Thanks Lix. I saw now

Answer (score 4):

You have actually multiple JSON objects. It is therefore invalid JSON to parse them as one.

The first JSON stops after the closing parenthesis:

```
{"total":null,"data":null}
```